# Logging the actual file/directory on SFTP "no such file" failure

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

We use Spring Integration fairly heavily and it works great. However, I'm unsure how to get Jsch/Spring Integration to log the actual file that is in question, when I get an error thrown from, for example, trying to do a list on a directory that does not exist on an sftp server. I get exceptions like the below.

Is there any way to coax either Spring Integration or Jsch to print out information on the file for "No such file"? When I looked at Jsch code it did not seem like there was any logging for that particular issue, but I may have missed something, and even if it does not have something, maybe the Spring code that is catching this exception has some context that it could log.

As it is, we either have to attach a debugger in instances like this, or try to make an educated guess about what directory or directories we may have to set up.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to list files; nested exception is 2: No such file
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:444)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:235)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to list files; nested exception is 2: No such file
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:104)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.list(CachingSessionFactory.java:218)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:239)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:235)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:435)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: No such file
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
```

Comment: Why don't you set the file name in the message header and log it inside your exception handler?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I'm not sure I see a clear way into doing that in all cases. For example, we use int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter, and that feeds into a channel upon seeing a file, for instance. Is there a way to add to the header the remote-directory value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened [INT-4534](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4534) to add the directory to the exception.